# ValueError: Unknown loss function: w_categorical_crossentropy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_modeleffusion():
    return tf.keras.models.load_model("C:/User/Downloads/modelEffusion.h5")




def make_predictioneffusion(uploaded_image, model):
    uploaded_image.save("out.jpg")
    image = cv2.imread("out.jpg")
    image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(256, 256))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = np.array(image)
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
    prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(image))
    return prediction

fileeffusion = st.file_uploader("Please upload an Xray scan file", type=["jpg", "png"],key= "Effusion")
st.set_option('deprecation.showfileUploaderEncoding', False)

modeleffusion = load_modeleffusion()
if fileeffusion is None:
   st.text("Please upload an image file")
else:
    image2 = Image.open(fileeffusion)
    st.image(image2, use_column_width=True)
    predictions = make_predictioneffusion(image2, modeleffusion)
    if st.button("Predict", key= "Effusionbutton"):
        if predictions == 0:
            string = "This is Effusion"
        elif predictions == 1.:
            string = " This is Normal"
        st.success(string)
```

I am trying a model for effusion disease and try to express as website using streamlit. When I try to run the model using tf.keras.models.load_model("C:/Users/fahad/Downloads/modelEffusion.h5") ==> this command.It says ValueError: Unknown loss function: w_categorical_crossentropy.Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument.
I dont know, how to solve this error.

Comment: The error telsls you exactly what to do, what is this "w_categorical_crossentropy" loss function?

Comment: I tried this command ==> **tf.keras.models.load_model("C:/User/Downloads/modelEffusion.h5",custom_objects={"w_categorical_crossentropy" : w_categorical_crossentropy )**. The error is solved but I get one sided output. Everytime I run a model with Xray images , it says Effusion only. Is there any method to solve this issue?